# Why does unbinding a texture from a FBO clear the texture?

Tags: opengl, fbo

I'm having some trouble with a render-to-texture operation.  I create a FBO, attach a texture, render to it, and everything's fine, but when I try to change the attached texture, either to 0 or to a new handle, by calling `glFramebufferTexture2DEXT` again, the texture I had attached becomes blank (all pixel values reset to (0, 0, 0, 0)).

[The documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture.xml) doesn't say that this is supposed to happen, and it's a bit troublesome for me because I need to retain the information in this texture.  Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to prevent or work around it?

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug, but we would need to see your code to be certain.

Comment: @Nicol: There's really not much to see.  I bind the texture to the FBO, I call `glDrawArrays` a few times to render onto it, then I try to bind a different texture.  I've verified it in gDEBugger.  Immediately before I call `glFramebufferTexture2DEXT`, the texture bound to the FBO was full of data.  Immediately after, it's blank.

Comment: Are you sure you're not deleting texture object somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a nearly the same situation. The end solution was when we were creating the texture we had to make sure to set up the TexParameters.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

According to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER defaults to  GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR but we weren't mipmapping. I am not sure why that would cause the texture to appear to be erased, but that is what we did to fix it.